# get count of different EF entities in single call?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to get the count of several entity collections through entity framework, and I would like to do this in a single call if possible.

my current code causes 4 separate sql queries. so id like to combine all 4 into one single query if possible.

```
var stats = new StatsVm()
            {
                StudentCount = _db.Students.All().Count(),
                InstructorCount = _db.Instructors.All().Count(),
                CourseCount = _db.Courses.All().Count(),
                DepartmentCount =  _db.Departments.All().Count()
            };
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Union`?

Comment: That could work. Could you provide an example please. thanks

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score -1):

EF doesn't allow query batching. In NHibernate you can use futures or batch queries for this.

Comment: OP asked to use EF, not NHibernate

Comment: Yes, I know... I didn't say "use NHibernate", I just mentioned that this is supported in NHibernate but not in EF.